# Jquery Mobile click event stop working/firing after a couple of times

Tags: jquery, events, mobile

I have an HTML file with two Jquery Mobile pages

```
<!-- Home Page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h1>FortiSizer</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
            <div id="myForm"></div>
            <a id="sizeit" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="false">Size It</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery("#home").on('pageinit', function(event, data) {
                 jQuery("#sizeit").on("click",function(e){
                    sizeItClick();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Product Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="productInfo">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <a id="back" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        <h1 id="productName"></h1>
    </div>

        <div data-role="content">
                 <div id="detail"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

In the head section I have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).on('pagecreate', function(event, data) {
            generatePageForm();
        });
</script>
```

That generates a form in the home page. The main idea is to show product details (Product Page) once the user selects a model form a select element. It all works fine, twice!

The form is generated, I click the "sizeIt" button, the Product details page loads, I click the back button on that page, and get back to the Home page. But by the third time I do this the sizeit button stops working, and the Product Page does not show up.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Might be the pageinit event not firing after back button usage, try using pageshow instead:
([jQuery mobile's pageinit causing problems on navigating back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041748/jquery-mobiles-pageinit-causing-problems-on-navigating-back))

```
jQuery("#home").on('pageshow', function(event, data) {
             jQuery("#sizeit").on("click",function(e){
                sizeItClick();
                return false;
            });
        });
```